# Truncate a file to a size in bytes

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to create another file from an existing file; the resulting file is identical to the original file. However I need the resulting file database.test to only have 1024 bytes of the original file (database.1). Can someone give me some quick solution to do this is code. Below is my code.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\PROGRAMS\DATABASE.1")
        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\programs\database.test", data)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How about, instead of writing all the bytes, you just write 128 of them? There must be some way to look up how to do that... and then you'll find how to read just 128 bytes.

Comment: Your database will be unusable, if you truncate it. Unless it's not a pure text file. In which case I wouldn't call it "database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions :-

I finally got it to work this way :-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\PROGRAMS\DATABASE.1")
        'File.WriteAllBytes("c:\programs\database.test", data)

        Using writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(File.Open("c:\programs\database.test", FileMode.Create))

            Dim x As Single = data.Length - 1

            Dim l As Single = 0

            For l = 0 To 1023

                writer.Write(data(l))

            Next



        End Using



    End Sub
```

Comment: That's writing 1024 *bytes* - your question stated 1024 *bits*.

Comment: sorry that had to be bytes ! !